# Nodemon server instance already running

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, server, nodemon

The error I am getting is server instance is already running on this port :: (any port could be 3000 or other) giving same error on all. I am using Windows.

This is the index.js file that Nodemon picks:

```
var express = require ("express");
var app = express();

// sets port 8080 to default or unless otherwise specified in the environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

// Only works on 3000 regardless of what I set environment port to or how I set
// [value] in app.set('port', [value]).
// app.listen(3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

This one is the db.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

  // use `await mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/test');` if your database has auth enabled
}
```

The problem is that there is already a server running whichever port I select in my code, so I first got its pid (process id) using this command

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000
```

Then I killed the port which was already running using this command

```
taskkill /F /PID <PID>
```

But after doing this, the ports get automatically started when again I try to use nodemon.

I also ended the ports of node js from the task manager but it also didn't work.